# Can $E=mc^2$ be derived from the Minkowski spacetime metric? $s^2=x^2+y^2+z^2-(ct)^2$?

Tags: special-relativity, energy-conservation, relativity, mass-energy

Can $E=mc^2$ be derived from the Minkowski spacetime metric? $s^2=x^2+y^2+z^2-(ct)^2$?

If so, how?

Can the equivalence of mass and energy be derived from the Minkowski spacetime metric?

Has someone done this somewhere?  Please do share the link/derivation/proof!

Basically what I am asking is if the Minkowski spacetime metric is enough to imply the equivalence of mass and energy as stated in $E=mc^2$.

Thanks! :)

Comment: Though it is quite orthogonal to your question I would encourage you to *not* imagine that $E = mc^2$ is in anyway emblematic of relativity. If you really must chose an equation for such a purpose you should be using $(mc^2)^2 = E^2 - (\vec{p}c)^2$. This reduces to the simpler form when $m \ne 0$ and $\vec{p} = 0$ but covers cases the other does not *and* gives mass it's proper definition as a Lorentz invariant.

Comment: Thanks!  Can (mc2)2=E2−(p⃗ c)2(mc2)2=E2−(p→c)2 be derived from the Minkowski spacetime metric?  :)

Comment: Look at [our formatting page](http://physics.stackexchange.com/editing-help) for some minimal information about using the MathJax markup tool for mathematics.

Comment: Basically you are asking if,or why, the metric in position space is or implies the same metric in momentum space. Good question.

Comment: @dmckee: it's definitely better to think of the formula as you wrote it. But isn't $E=m_0\gamma c^2$ as opposed to $E=mv^2/2$ really emblematic for relativity? Einsteins formula doesn't say something about a new mysterious lorentz scalar! - it gives the old Newtonian mass (in the sense of inertness) a new broader meaning. Isn't this what stands *really* behind this question for the normal (nearer to the classical beginnings) scolar of physical concepts?

Comment: @Ilja Most professionals in relativity have long since discarded the notion of "relativistic mass", and use *only* the invariant mass so they don't write $m_0$ because there is only $m$ which is not a function of velocity. There are a lot of questions around the site that touch on it, but http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/133376/why-is-there-a-controversy-on-whether-mass-increases-with-speed is probably the best. On top of which the form you suggest doesn't deal with massless particles.

Comment: @Ilja "relativistic mass" as a concept needs to die because it's outdated, useless, inelegant, confusing, and most importantly, a complete pedagogical disaster.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of the correct relativistic interpretation ;) But nevertheless the beauty and fascination is, that those things coincide with the normal classical mass and classical speed of light. And I would definitely not say, that it's a pedagogical disaster to search for the relationship of the correct (and therefore more abstract) physical theories to everyday life ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Minkowski spacetime has the symmetries of the Poincaré group, which include the four spacetime translations. Noether's theorem then says that there are four conserved quantities, $p_0, p_1, p_2, p_3$, associated with these four symmetries. Typically $p_0$ is denoted by $E$. The structure of the Poincare group implies that these four quantities are related like the components of a four-vector. Thus $p_0^2 - p_1^2 - p_2^2 - p_3^2 = m^2$ is a relativistically invariant conserved quantity. This should be understood as the *definition* of $m$. If $m^2 > 0$, there exist observers such that $p_0 = E = m$, and $p_1 = p_2 = p_3 = 0$. But in physics we often consider systems such that $m = 0$, and then it is *not* possible to make $p_1=p_2=p_3=0$, so we need the more general formula to cover all interesting cases.

(I'm using units where $c = 1$.)